# How to let UIViewController be the UIWindow's rooViewController when initialized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I'm making a framework. But at the end, I met a problem about the `rootViewController` of `UIWindow`.
I have a subclass of `UIViewController`, with a method called `- (void)showLogin` inside the class.

I know I could use `[self.window setRootViewController:myClass];` to let app get rootViewController. But I only want use the one method `[[WDLoginViewController sharedInstance] showLogin];` to achieve the same effect.

To do that, anyone could give me some advice?

### My .h class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WDLoginViewController : UIViewController 

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
- (void)showLogin;

@end
```

### My AppDelegate.m class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [[WDLoginViewController sharedInstance] showLogin];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to use a storyboard and set your login controller as the initial view controller. You would store the login ID in a singleton somewhere else -- not in the view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve with below code :-

```
//In your WDLoginViewController

//Create this property in .h file or .m file
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *rootWindow;

-(void)showLogin {
  self.rootWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

  [self.rootWindow setRootViewController:self];
  [self.rootWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: I decide to use `rootViewController` property in the `AppDelegate.m`. So could I write the code like that `[self.window setRootViewController:[WDLoginViewController sharedInstance]];`? If this is not very elegant?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want set the controller you don't use a controller use a view. But i recommend you to use `setRootViewController`, you have to have a rotViewController. Maybe try to use `presentViewController` to the controller you use with `setRootViewController` to load your controller `WDLoginViewController`.

Comment: I thought twice, and yours is better. I'll try the way, Thank you.

Comment: There are many ways of doing things, it's just follow convention.